# Best cluster approach for dichotomous variables in SPSS

Tags: spss, binary-data, hierarchical-clustering

I'm reading contradictory information on the internet and wanted to get some thoughts on a statistical approach to use. I'll use a fictional example for the sake of easy interpretation.

I have a set of eight different dichotomous variables that represent presence or absence of a symptom. For example, 'Pain' (yes/no), 'Nausea' (yes/no), etc. Of course, I've coded them all as 1/0 for presence/absence.

I want to see whether certain symptoms cluster together. My recruited sample size is fairly large at 1575, though I want to contrast the clusters in two subgroups of 516 individuals with a disease and 1059 without. I like the idea of a dendrogram, so Hierarchical Cluster Analysis seems to make sense to me, but IBM recommend only using Two-Step analysis for categorical data. I don't think k-means makes sense (nor indeed k-modes) since I'm using dichotomous variables. I've seen a research paper in my field that used HCA with dendrogram and a cut-off correlation value to select the number of clusters. They just didn't rationalise their approach, so I'm not sure if it's statistically accurate to do so.

I'd like the leaves from the cluster analysis to represent the symptoms, much as the countries do in this image from the internet:

[image]

The general purpose of the statistical analysis is to identify whether certain symptoms cluster together, both in the non-disease (n=1059) and in the disease groups (n=516). If there are differences in the clusters, it might indicate an underlying biological mechanism that could later be explored. I'm using the latest SPSS, so advice for that software would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The clusters define themselves without any need for a special clustering method. That is, there are $2^8 = 256$ possibilities. With good fortune, they won't all occur in your dataset. I would just define the clusters as composite binary variables from 00000000 (0) to 11111111 (255) and count their frequencies. I have no idea how to do that in SPSS, sorry, as I haven't used it since the last millennium.

For visualization, what is now often called an UpSetPlot (various more or less cute variations in spelling exist) can be helpful. If it's too crowded to be much use, any dendrogram would be too crowded too. There seem to be implementations in most of the standard statistical environments. Again, sorry, I have no specific information on SPSS.

I am most familiar with an implementation in Stata [discussed here](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1696288-upsetplot-now-available-from-ssc).

Comment: Thanks Nick. I don't think this is what I want to achieve. If I followed the approach you suggest, I would end up with a simple count of the number of different combinations of symptoms. My understanding is that clustering is different in that the statistical engine uses different thresholds to identify at what point a relationship between symptoms is present or absent. This is what generates the different branches. I'm looking for branching!

Comment: What thresholds would they be? All your characters are binary and differ from each other by 0 or 1 along each axis.

Comment: That's my question. I'm not sure how the statistical software chooses a threshold, nor indeed which one to choose. In the example I cited, the authors showed clustering using HEA at different thresholds that were determined by strength of correlation coefficient. They chose (arbitrarily I think) a cut-off value of r=.67 to identify how many clusters they had. I'm confused because (a) IBM say not to use HEA with dichotomous data, (b) I'm not certain how to set the analysis up to even do this, (c) I don't know if those chose a statistically sound approach.

Comment: Correspondence analysis might help.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform hierarchical cluster analysis of features that are discrete or binary (0,1) if the distance metric used during agglomeration is set to Tanimoto distance.  There's a binary form of Tanimoto and a continuous form.

[image]

Comment: Thanks - I'll read about that!